# background-image pseudo z-index

Tags: css, background-image, z-index, layer

I have a `<ul>` with multiple background images.
Problem is that `<li>`s have a `border-bottom` that goes above one background-image (in this case the arrow). I'd like the arrow to be a layer UP the border-bottom. You can see the overlap here:
[image: Overlap]

And [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/gz7pa/)'s a JsFiddle that reproduces the `<ul>`.
[Here](http://multiformeingegno.it/) is the live site instead.

I know it's not possible to set a z-index for the background images, but is there a trick (or, better, a clean way, to avoid this overlap and set the border-bottom a layer below or the background-image a layer above)?

**EDIT:** Setting `.box ul li {position: relative;z-index: -1}` makes the arrow go above the `border-bottom` but links are not clickable anymore: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gz7pa/2/) :(

Comment: You would need to place the background images in a separate container and absolutely position it over the list items... a bit of work but doable.  Would such a solution work in your context?

Comment: Uhm.. wouldn't that work only on a specific resolution?

Comment: It would work for any resolution.  It may need an extra tag to place the images but that is it.  I saw an answer earlier using `z-index: -1`, did that work out?

Comment: Nope. :( Added info on the question. Can I ask you a fiddle with your solution...? :)

Comment: I tried out my solution at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/gz7pa/4/ As you can see, the blue arrow is now over the border but whenever you mouse over the rectangle that holds the images, you can't click the link.  This may or may not be suitable, but at least you can take a look.

Comment: For now it's the best semi-acceptable solution! thanks! :D

Comment: The only problem is that with Mobile Safari I get this: http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/1150/08e4ab9b8f3248dea9acab9.png (and the image on the question was from Mobile Safari too). EDIT: cache was cleared

Comment: Hi! Actually, the problem is with Safari in general (Windows version too), so if I can fix that, it might solve your problem.  Safari supports CSS3 multiple image, so let me check into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may be an option.

For the HTML:

```
<div style="list-style-type:none;width:400px" class="box">
    <ul id="lastfm">
        <li>...</li>
        ...
        <li class="overlay"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add an extra item `li.overlay` and attach the background images to it using the CSS:

```
.box ul#lastfm {
    padding-right: 75px;
    position: relative; /* So that the absolute positioning based on this block... */
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: square outside none;
}

.overlay {
    outline: 1px dashed blue; /* for demo only */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; /* to make sure it is in front of list items... */
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px; /* will depend on your images... */
    width: 110px;
    background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
    background-clip: border-box, border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: ...
    background-origin: padding-box, padding-box;

    background-position: right bottom, right bottom, left 0px;
    /* Make sure syntax is correct, otherwise Safari gets confused... */

    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto, 70px auto, auto auto;
}
```

Make sure that the syntax for `background-position` is absolutely correct otherwise Safari will not be able to figure it out.  Firefox was a bit more forgiving.

Demo is at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/GpAek/